# bash mv is not a directory

Tags: bash, recursion, move

I have this:

```
$ ls a
0  1  1_  2  2_  3  3_  4  4_  5  5_  6  6_  7  7_  8  8_  9  9_  a  a_  b  b_  c  c_ 
d  d_  e  e_  f  f_
```

And want to move the x_ to x, I'm trying this:

```
find a/*_ -type f -exec sh -c 'mv echo "$1" echo "$1" | sed \'\$s/.$//'' sh {} \;
```

What I'm getting is:

```
mv: target `a/x_' is not a directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use prename ;)

```
prename 's/.$//' a/*_
```

Depends of your distro, sometimes called just rename. Sometimes there's one in ELF format, but the perl one is required, you can test that like this : `file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use:

```
(cd a; for file in *_; do mv "$file" "${file%_}"; done)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in {1..9}; do test -e $f_ && mv ${f}_ $f ; done
for f in {a..d}; do test -e $f_ && mv ${f}_ $f ; done
```

The test could be made finer to check if $f_ is a file by  `test -f $f_`, and I could provide a test to ensure, that $f exists and is a directory:

```
for f in {1..9} {a..d}
do 
    test -f $f_ && test -d $f && mv ${f}_ $f
done
```

If there is no directory $f, the above command would rename $f_ to $f, and if $f exists, and is a file, overwrite.

Comment: The trouble with this in the general case is that there could be a file `x` where there is no file `x_` (so it would report an error), and it would miss a file `y_` where there is no file `y`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Okay - I added a test for existence of `$f_`. I don't think I should create a directory y if it doesn't exist.